# How project/wizard is associated with perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

After we create a new project in eclipse, a dialog will be showed as following picture if our current perspective is not associated with this kind of project. So how do Eclipse make this programmatically?

[image: Associated with perspective]

I think it depends on the project nature but the `perspective extension point` has nothing to connect with the project nature.

Tks for your time :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `finalPerspective` attribute in your wizard. See 
[Associating a Wizard with a Perspective](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tips/11-associating-wizard-perspective) for reference:

1. Add the `finalPerspective` attribute to the definition of our wizard element in the extension.
2. Make the Wizard class implement the interface `IExecutableExtension`. This interface has only one method `setInitializationData`. Implement the method in the class and assign the parameter `IConfigurationElement` to a field in the method.
3. In the `performFinish` method of the Wizard, call `BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.updatePerspective` method.